# How to retrieve data from database into JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, resultset

Hi I want to fetch data from  database and display into `JTable`. How can I achieve this?

Here is my table  query for table:

```
select id,name,father from  employee
```

Here  is my code:

```
public static void main( String[] str ) {
        String[] colName = new String[] { "Product Name" ,"Price" };
        Object[][] products = new Object[][] {
                { "Galleta" ,"$80" },
                { "Malta" ,"$40" },
                { "Nestea" ,"$120" }
          };

        JTable table = new JTable( products, colName );
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Simple Table Example" );
        // create scroll pane for wrapping the table and add
        // it to the frame
        frame.add( new JScrollPane( table ) );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
```

Comment: Either use a `ResultSetTableModel` (search on that term), or iterate the result set and put each entry into a custom table model of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Vector` here

Code as follows

```
        Dbconnection obj=new Dbconnection();
        rs=obj.getWorkers();// rs is ResultSet object And getWorkers() is just a method in class Dbconnection
        Vector v1=new Vector();
        v1.addElement("ID");   //column name in JTable
        v1.addElement("NAME"); //column name in JTable
        v1.addElement("STATE"); //column name in JTable
        v1.addElement("MOB");   //column name in JTable
        Vector v3=new Vector(); //column name  in JTable 
        try{
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Vector v2=new Vector();
            v2.addElement(rs.getString(8));  // 8 is column number,And it depends on your query 
            v2.addElement(rs.getString(2));  // 2 is column number,And it depends on your query
            v2.addElement(rs.getString(6));  // 6 is column number,And it depends on your query
            v2.addElement(rs.getString(7)); // 7 is column number,And it depends on your query
        v3.add(v2);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){}
        JTable wrkr_table=new JTable(v3, v1);
        wrkr_table.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        JScrollPane scp=new JScrollPane(wrkr_table);
        scp.setBounds(50,100,680,110);
        frame.add(scp);
```

Reffer [Vector](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_vector_class.htm)